# Create JUnit test for SendGrid

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, sendgrid

I want to create the JUnit test for checking mail from SendGrid.
I have class A and there I have the method `send` who have implementation for sending mail.:

```
public void send(Mail mail, String sendGridKey) throws IOException {
    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(sendGridKey);
    Request request = new Request();

    try {
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());
        Response response = sg.api(request);            
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And I created the Junit test :

```
Assert.assertEquals( email.send(mail, SENDGRID_API_KEY), "");
```

and I have this error:

```
The method assertEquals(Object, Object) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (void, String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assertEquals()` method is checking the first parameter (expected) and the second parameter (actual value) for equality. In your case it will check the return parameter of the method `email.send()` for equality with an empty `String` `""`. This will not work, because the `email.send()` is a void method and therefore has no return value (such as `String`).

You could either change the method signature to `public String send(Mail mail, String sendGridKey)` or work with the `@Test(expected = IOException.class)` on top of your test method to check if an exception was thrown (see: [exceptionThrownBaeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception))

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any different approach to my problem?